# Packing React App: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled

Tags: reactjs, npm, package.json

I'm trying to package app "x" and use that in another app "y".
Here's my setup:

x/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "x",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "antd": "^5.8.6",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.7",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.9",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  },
  "exports": {
    "./components/": "./src/components/"
  }
}
```

y/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "y",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "x": "file:x-0.0.1.tgz"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11"
  }
}
```

I'm using `npm pack` to package the "x" app, and install it by adding it to the "dependencies" section in y/package.json.

The install works fine, but when I try to start the "y" app I get:

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled
```

On code in the "x" package.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The project mentioned in your question seems to be something resembling to a Monorepo Architecture which means using single repo for multiple applications.

Lerna is a tool for bootraping, building and releasing packages. It helps to simply manage multiple apps. It allows you to easily manage versioning, dependencies, and publishing of packages within a Monorepo. Lerna Monorepo structure may look like something similar to this:

```
monorepo/
|
|-- packages/
|   |
|   |-- package-a/
|   |   |
|   |   |-- src/
|   |   |-- test/
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |
|   |-- package-b/
|   |   |
|   |   |-- src/
|   |   |-- test/
|   |   |-- package.json
|   |
|   |-- shared-code/
|
|-- lerna.json
|-- yarn.lock
```

First you can initialize Lerna:

```
npx lerna@latest init
```

Then create Lerna packages:

```
npx lerna create <package-name>
```

Then add dependancies:

```
npx lerna add <package-name> --scope=<package-B>
```

Then build, test and publish.

```
npx lerna run build
npx lerna run test
npx lerna publish
```

By using Monorepos, developers can share code and dependencies between packages, versioning and publishing the packages and manage dependencies easily.

For your reference:

[How to? Resolve multiple React apps to same 'react' package PATH using webpack/lerna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62353453/how-to-resolve-multiple-react-apps-to-same-react-package-path-using-webpack-l)

https://dev.to/danireptor/introduction-to-monorepo-in-react-1b3a

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I already solved the issue in a different way but I'll give this a try as well.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **.babelrc** in root project have right presets for react jsx

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

and your **tsconfig.json** supports

```
"jsx": "react-jsx"
```

If the error persists, create a babel.config.js file in the root directory and set the presets there as well.

Comment: Hi, Do I need to put it in the source project X or in the destination project Y?
I don't have ts.config or babelrc in either of them.

Comment: Typically this is needed in both projects

Comment: tsconfig is needed only if you have typescript enabled

Comment: Have you created babelrc? Did it help to your question?

Comment: Hey, I did and it didn't help. I've ended up going entirely different route. Using create-react-library and local registry to publish to. Thank you for your suggestion.